# When to use May Have & probably in Sentence?

Tags: modal-verbs

We use either **may + have** and **might + have** to show that something has *possibly happened now* or *happened at some time in the past*. ([Learnenglish.britishcouncil.org](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/modal-verbs/may-might-may-have-and-might-have))

What is the difference between the two answers this question? (Which one is correct?)

Question: Where has he gone?

---

Answer 1: Probably, he has gone to the canteen.

Answer 2: He may have gone to the canteen.

Comment: Either may be valid, but they do not mean the same thing: the first asserts that his going there is probable, the second that it is possible. . . . By the way, Anglo-American Englishes call for an article before *canteen*.

Comment: Anybody in here knows how to change my review from Approved to Rejected?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two is the probability they implied.  **May have** suggests a possibility without any comment on its probability.  **Probably**, meanwhile, suggests something is likely to have happened.  Say "probably" if you're pretty sure he went to the canteen; say "may have" if you think it's possible but don't really know either way.